# Simple Jquery Display on MouseEnter Question

Tags: jquery, html, button, bind

I am new to stackoverflow and Jquery so I would like to apologize for my inexperience/naivety in advance.

So essentially I am attempting to make a div appear when a button is in the mouseEnter state.

Here's my attempt at Jquery...

```
$('#main-button-btn-cart').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var $select_button = $('#select-product-reminder');

    $select_button.style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

and the HTML is...

```
  <div id="select-product-reminder" style="width:200px; height:30px; background-color:#F00; display:none;">Please Choose an Item</div>
    <button type="button" id="main-button-btn-cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()">
      <?php echo $this->__('+ADD TO CART') ?>
    </button>
```

For some reason this code does not work.  However, it may be useful to note that if I include an alert box in my bind function, the alert box does appear.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick;

```
$('#main-button-btn-cart').mouseenter(function() {
    var $select_button = $('#select-product-reminder');
    $($select_button).css('display','inline-block');
});
```

Or you could do away with the var;

```
$('#main-button-btn-cart').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#select-product-reminder').css('display','inline-block');
});
```

**Update for click;**

```
$('#main-button-btn-cart').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#select-product-reminder').css('display','inline-block');
  $(this).click(function() {
    alert('You clicked the button');
  });
});
```

Comment: Now I am trying to change the onclick value for the submit button as well.  How would I do that with using Jquery?

Comment: @Rbacarin Not necessarily true. .show() will set the element to display:block; - Some elements require display: inline; specifically IE6, for double margin bugs on floated block elements. Therefore the .css method would be more suited.

@thepristinedesign What do you want to set the onclick value to? Or do you simply want it to run a function?

Comment: +1 for browser compatibility consideration, and in keeping with what the OP was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
$('#main-button-btn-cart').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#select-product-reminder').show();
});
```

also you can do this

```
$('#main-button-btn-cart').onmouseenter(function() {
    $('#select-product-reminder').show();
});
```

onmouseenter is a short cut instead of calling bind function

Answer (score 0):

I would use something that look like this:
    $('#main-button-btn-cart').live('mouseenter',function() {
     $('#select-product-reminder').show();
   });